# angular2-webpack-starter best way to customize production baseUrl

Tags: angular, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using angular2-webpack-starter 5.4.1.  https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

To customize baseUrl for production build, in config/webpack.prod.js, I am just repeating what is done in config/webpack.common.js.

```
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2290 from @AngularClass',
  baseUrl: '/apps/awesomeapp',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};
```

and then:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.html',
    title: METADATA.title,
    chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
    metadata: METADATA,
    inject: 'head'
  }),
```

This works but smells bad.  Ideally, I should only need to change the METADATA.baseUrl variable in config/webpack.prod.js.

Has anyone found a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what I did for a configuration for PostCSS.

```
const postcssShared = [
    require("level4")()
];

const postcssProduction = [
    require("css-mqpacker")(),
    require("postcss-fixes")(),
    require("postcss-mq-keyframes")(),
    require("postcss-will-change")(),
    require("postcss-cssnext")({
        browsers: [ ">2%" ]
    }),
    require("postcss-discard-comments")(),
    require("cssnano")({
        autoprefixer: false,
        calc: false,
        safe: true
    })
];

module.exports = {
    development: postcssShared,
    production: postcssShared.concat(postcssProduction)
};
```

The basics of this is that you import the import the production configuration for the production build and development for the development build.